# select tag using $(this), from ajaxform plugin constructor

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors, ajaxform

Note : I have titled it very poorly, please help me improve it, if you understand my question

I am using [**ajaxform**](http://malsup.com/jquery/form) submit for all of my forms. I am able to programatically add a feedback div to each form successfully. I **want to select only current form** in my page. I am using following code.

```
 $('form').append('<div class="feedback" />');
    $('form').ajaxForm
    ({      
        success: function(responseText)
        {
            if(responseText=="1")
            {           
                $(this).clearForm();
                $(this).children('INPUT,select').eq(0).focus();
            }
            else    
            {
                alert($(this).children().length); // This gives me 0
                $(this).children('.feedback').eq(0).html(responseText); 
            }
        }
    });
```

I can do the above successfully  only if I have one form in whole page using **$('form') instead of $(this)** but it makes problem when i have multiple forms in a page

Comment: what is the problem you are facing and can you please show the HTML?

Comment: can u see plz `alert($(this).children().length); // This gives me 0` in qestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look closer at the docs, will see that the `success` callback is passed 4 arguments

```
1.) responseText or responseXML value (depending on the value of the dataType option).
2.) statusText
3.) xhr (or the jQuery-wrapped form element if using jQuery < 1.4)
4.) jQuery-wrapped form element (or undefined if using jQuery < 1.4)
```

Use the last argument instead of `$(this)` for current form instance

**[See options tab of docs](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#options-object)**

**Update by asker :** working code from above answer I got is following

Instead of `$(this)` I could do following

```
$('form').append('<div class="feedback" />');
var options = { success: showResponse  };
$('form').ajaxForm(options);
function showResponse(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form)
{
    if(statusText == 'success')     
        $form.children('.feedback').html(responseText);
}
```

**[Link of example followed](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#ajaxForm)**

Answer (score 1):

$(this) will only work if the context of the invocation for the success callback is the form node itself.

If it's not working, you can always cache the reference and you will have access to it in the scope of your callback:

```
var $form = $('form');

$form.ajaxForm({
    success: function (responseText) {

        $form.clearForm();

    }
});
```

I did not include your logic with the response because response is an object with several unique properties. See the answer by **@charlietfl** for the properties

```
------ UPDATE ---------
```

If the problem you have is that you need access to **that** form after appending the div, remember that "append", along with all other jQuery methods affecting a node, are chainable:

```
$('form').append('<div>My Div</div>').ajaxForm(options....)
```

Hopefully the context of the invocation of the success handler is the form node itself, if not you can cache the reference as I did above.

Comment: would still affect all forms on page due to collection `$('form')`

Comment: you are still caching the whole collection, so instance is not exposed using `$form`. Another way is loop over `$form.each` and then cache instance within that loop and initialize plugin on instance

Comment: context of operation differs and this does not work. However good to explain about $(this) thanks +1. And sorry that it was more about ajaxform rather than jquery-selector. See my edit in accepted answer. Though your answer not produced expected result still it was need to me more than the correct (in my this scenario) one.